# Why strings are shown partially in the Visual Studio 2008 debugger?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, string, debugging

I'm debugging a C++ application with VS2008 and with some long select queries I'm not able to see the full text in the debugger. It just shows a part of the query.

Is there a way to see the full text?

Thanks in advance.

[image]

EDIT: The real query available at the string is:

```
select  c.cd_seq, m.diag_code, m.diag_descr, 'S' as source 
from custom_booking_data c 
left outer join meddiagnosis m 
on c.cd_number_value = convert( decimal( 28, 8 ), m.diag_urn ) 
where c.custom_data_urn = 4 and c.cd_field = 433 
union 
select  c.cd_seq, m.diag_code, m.diag_descr, 'H' as source 
from custom_booking_data c 
left outer join ordiagnosis m 
on c.cd_number_value = convert( decimal( 28, 8 ), m.diag_urn ) 
where c.custom_data_urn = 4 and c.cd_field = 594
```

Not that long if you ask me.

Comment: How long are we talking here?  I've viewed stuff that was 10,000-20,000 characters long without truncation.  In your case it looks like it's in an ATL::CString.  Does that have the correct length?  Perhaps the string is actually truncated.

Comment: Click the text visualizer icon, looks like a spyglass.  If that still clips, definitely consider simplifying your queries.

Comment: Its a string of about 1.000 characters and yes, it's an ATL:CString. How to check if it has the correct length? I know the full query its there because it gets executed and the expected results are retrieved.

Comment: Same here with VS2015 Update 1: string truncated to 32768 (or more specifically: the first 16382 characters followed by "..." followed by the final 16383 characters). Any solutions?

Comment: @D.R. - I have encountered the same 32768 character problem, also using VS2015.1. Can easily be reproduced with `new string(' ', 32769)`. I've looked around and haven't found any other question anywhere that mentions this. Visual Studio 2013 is fine with it and shows the whole string.

Comment: Funny update: VS 2015 has no problems -> VS 2015 Update 1 introduces the problem. Workaround: `File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Temp\temp.txt", str)` in the immediate window.

Answer (score 17):

Hover the variable you want to view, then click on the **magnifier icon** following icon, or select the arrow right to the icon and select Text from the drop down menu

[image]

This is the result, i think you asked this...

[image]

Comment: Indeed, does not help with strings longer than 32768 characters.

Comment: It seems that VS2015 can show longer than 32K characters on this form. There should still be a limit, but at least it's higher than that.

Comment: In VisualStudio 2017 there seems to be a limit of a little bit more than 1 million characters (char).

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be a 'feature' in Visual Studio.  I see the same thing in VS2012 using C#, with a string that is just over 500 characters.

The solution that I found was to right click on the variable in the debugger and do a 'Quick Watch' on it.  The string is not truncated in the Quick Watch window.

Comment: Does not help with strings longer than 32768 characters.

Answer (score 1):

Could it be that your string contains NUL '\0' values? Textbox controls like the ones the debugger is using will interpret them as the end of the string.

Comment: Nope, I checked that but the query is broken in middle of a working union select "union sele"

Answer (score 1):

This is in a comment but really is the answer I was looking for: `File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Temp\temp.txt", str)`

Comment: this does not work for c++? At least not in VS 2019

Answer (score 0):

I think you can right-click the item and then 'copy to clipboard'. Then paste it into another text editor.

Comment: Nope, the value is also copied partially.

Comment: Right click on the item in the debugger, do not copy the text from the textbox, then it is too late!

Comment: I've copied it from everywhere possible and the result is always the string truncated.

Comment: Can confirm that for VS2015 - strings longer than 32768 characters are cut down (see comment at question).

Comment: i was looking for a workaround, so selecting the whole object example: {content: "too long..."} did the trick. cheers!