# Debugger not showing entire string

Tags: vb.net, string, encoding, arrays

I get a `byte array` from a foreign `WebService`. To get the `string` out of it, I use the following line of code (I don't know the exact encoding):

```
Dim content As String = Encoding.Default.GetString(byteArray)
```

At the first look, it seems that this is working, but if I open the resulting `string` in debug mode in Visual Studio I just see 135 lines but it should be over 700. The strange thing is, if I write the string in a textfile, I have all lines in there?!

Here's the code to write the file:

```
IO.File.WriteAllText(path, content)
```

If I split the string and count the lines, I also get the right result:

```
Dim lines As Integer = content.Split(Environment.NewLine).Length
```

So why do I not see the whole text in Visual Studio?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why strings are shown partially in the Visual Studio 2008 debugger?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5394761/why-strings-are-shown-partially-in-the-visual-studio-2008-debugger)

Comment: thx @CodeCaster, i didn't expect, that the reason for that behavior could be so simple.