# Streamreader to String not working properly

Tags: json, vb.net

I am getting HttpWebResponse encoded in Base64
following lines get the webresponse from API.

```
Dim myResp As HttpWebResponse = myReq.GetResponse()
Dim myreader As New System.IO.StreamReader(myResp.GetResponseStream)
```

the response which i get is something like following, however actual response is too long and i cannot paste here so i have manually stripped the actual response.

```
{"status":"1","data":"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"}
```

I am not sure why above Base64 Encoded message starts with **{"status":"1","data":"** and then ends with **"}**.

Actual Base64 data starts after  {"status":"1","data":"

Due to those unsupported characters at starting and  ending of the stream , i first try to convert actual response to string as shown below.

```
Dim myResp As HttpWebResponse = myReq.GetResponse()
Dim myreader As New System.IO.StreamReader(myResp.GetResponseStream)
```

Actual stream response returns around 248000 characters (as per response received in POSTMAN with same API). Streamreader information in Debug mode also shows same 248000 number. But when i convert them into string with following code line, string gets slimmed to around only 32000 characters. I don't know why this is happening?

```
Dim myText As String = myreader.ReadToEnd

'''Then following code will remove all those unwanted characters from starting string, which are {"status":"1","data":" 
Dim Final_text As String = myText.Substring(myText.Substring(0, myText.LastIndexOf("""")).LastIndexOf("""") + 1)

'''Following code will remove two characters "} from end of the string.
Final_text = Final_text.Trim().Remove(Final_text.Length - 2)

''' Now Decode this proper Base64 String to JSON format
Dim data As Byte() = Convert.FromBase64String(Final_text)
Dim decodedString As String = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data)

Dim JsonP As JObject = JObject.Parse(decodedString)       
Dim SetPointerOut As JToken = JsonP("b2b")
```

Two things: why converting from Stream to String cut down actual response? 248000 charters to just apprx. 32000 characters. In debug mode if i type in ?mytext.length it returns 248000 as value. But When i hover mouse and brows what is in mytext variable, it shows me around 32000 charters only.

Service provider says Response which i get from API  is Base64 encoded and i have to decode it before using it as JSON. Then why do i get unsupported characters at starting of the stream (even in Postman), is it Base64 Encoded message in serialized manner?

Am I doing right process to first convert the stream to string, remove unwanted characters and then Decode it? or there is some other way around.

Comment: The string returned is a JSON string, just parse it and then convert the base64 string

Comment: i guess i have to do that on mytext string, but then first issue is why mytext string does not contain my all 248000 characters received in response? if i am not getting full response in string, i think i cannot parse it properly in later stage, right?

Comment: Dim json As String = myText;  Dim jsonObject As Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(json); Dim jsonValue As JValue = jsonObject("data"),  but jsonvalue also has only 32000 characters. What i figured is if i see mytext as JSON Visualizer in debug then it shows 248000 characters under "Data" object, but if same variable as Text Visualizer then shows only 32000 characters

Comment: What is the length of _myText_? if it is already 32000 chars then is a problem in your stream, if it is bigger then is a problem in the deserialization

Comment: ok, i found issue with Text Visualizer, VS2015 have bug by which it shows only 32768 characters only. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5394761/why-strings-are-shown-partially-in-the-visual-studio-2008-debugger

Answer (score 0):

Ok, issue of 32768 character in debug mode of Visual Studio is it self.
VS2015 had bug in which it does not support more than 32768 characters. Read
[Why strings are shown partially in the Visual Studio 2008 debugger?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5394761/why-strings-are-shown-partially-in-the-visual-studio-2008-debugger)
and 
[Visual Studio Text Visualizer missing text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34054126/visual-studio-text-visualizer-missing-text)

The method which i was using to remove extra unwanted characters from "mytext" string, still works and give result. But as @Steve suggested in comment to the question, I should parse the JSON string. I find that idea much better and correct method.

so final code is like below:

```
Dim myResp As HttpWebResponse = myReq.GetResponse()
Dim myreader As New System.IO.StreamReader(myResp.GetResponseStream)
Dim myText As String = myreader.ReadToEnd
Dim json As String = myText
Dim jsonResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Dictionary(Of String, Object))(json)


Dim jsonObject As Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(json)
Dim jsonValue As JValue = jsonObject("data")

Dim Final_text As String = jsonValue.ToString

''' No need of following code as doing JSON parse above
''' Dim Final_text As String = myText.Substring(myText.Substring(0, myText.LastIndexOf("""")).LastIndexOf("""") + 1)

'''Final_text = Final_text.Trim().Remove(Final_text.Length - 2)

Dim data As Byte() = Convert.FromBase64String(Final_text)
Dim decodedString As String = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data)

Dim JsonP As JObject = JObject.Parse(decodedString)       
Dim SetPointerOut As JToken = JsonP("b2b")
```